# PostgreSQL table inheritance and moving rows with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, inheritance, orm, sqlalchemy

In my app (python, postgres, sqlalchemy) I had one large table `tasks`. The app mostly works with recent 1k rows in `tasks`, frequently selecting and updating rows. Such frequent operations were too slow due to size of `tasks` so I decided to split this table into two `tasks` `tasks_all`, where table `tasks` are inheried from `tasks_all` (postgresql feature).

Thus the app can work with a small table very fast and when it to do something to old data, it can work with the large table, that includes all rows from self and from it's successor.

Here is simplified classes for my tables:

```
class TaskBase:
    def __init__(self, id, parent_id, data):
        self.id = id
        self.parent_id = parent_id
        self.data = data

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Task: {} {}>'.format(self.id, self.data)


class Task(TaskBase, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tasks'

    id = Column(INT, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(INT, ForeignKey('tasks.id'))
    data = Column(TEXT)

    children = relationship("Task", backref=backref('parent', remote_side=[id]))


class TaskAll(TaskBase, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tasks_all'

    id = Column(INT, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(INT, ForeignKey('tasks_all.id'))
    data = Column(TEXT)

    children = relationship("TaskAll", backref=backref('parent', remote_side=[id]))
```

To keep `tasks` table small, I need time to time move rows from `tasks` to `tasks_all`. And sometimes I will need to move them back. The following code is how I tried to implement moving.

```
def move_group(ids):
    query = session.query(TaskAll).filter(TaskAll.id in ids)
    db_session.s.execute(insert(Task).from_select((
        TaskAll.id,
        TaskAll.parent_id,
        TaskAll.data,
    ), query))
    print("insert from select is successful")
    query.delete()
    print("delete is successful")
```

But this doesn't work because as table `tasks_all` is parent to `tasks`, delete from `tasks_all` also deletes from `tasks`. Resulting SQL query is:

```
DELETE FROM tasks_all WHERE tasks_all.id IN (...);
```

But to perform the operation I need, the query shuld be

```
DELETE FROM ONLY tasks_all WHERE tasks_all.id IN (...);
```

As far as I could find SQLAlchemy knows nothing about `ONLY`. Do I have to use raw SQL queries from sqla skipping ORM part, or maybe there is a better solution to move rows from one table to another?

Answer (score 1):

I found that SQLAlchemy has a hint mechanism that would help when doing operations in a table that was inherited.

```
def move_group(ids):
    query = session.query(TaskAll).filter(TaskAll.id in ids)
    db_session.s.execute(insert(Task).from_select((
        TaskAll.id,
        TaskAll.parent_id,
        TaskAll.data,
    ), query))
    print("insert from select is successful")
    query.delete().with_hint('ONLY', dialect_name='postgresql')
    print("delete is successful")
```

I know that the question was made some years ago, but I hope that it could still help someone.